# Accelerating scientific python program

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

I have the following code in python:

```
def P(z, u0):
    x = np.inner(z, u0)
    tmp = x*u0
    return (z - tmp)


def powerA2(A, u0):
    x0 = np.random.rand(len(A))
    for i in range(ITERATIONS):
        x0 = P(np.dot(A, x0), u0)
        x0 = x0 / np.linalg.norm(x0)
    return (np.inner(np.dot(A, x0), x0))
```

`np` is **`numpy`** package.

I am interested in running this code for matrices in size of 100,000 * 100,000, but it seems that there is no chance for this program to run fast (I need to run it many times, about 10,000).

**Is there any chance that tricks like multi-threading would work here?**

**Does anything else help to accelerate it?**

Comment: 100000^2 64bit reals would amount in something like 72 GB of memory. This is not a problem for you? First step for speeding this up, in my opinion would be to move to compiled language instead. I know numpy is doing this behind the scenes, still I would guess there is a lot of memory accesses that could be avoided by natively implementing this in a compiled language, and maybe calling that routine than in Python.

Comment: Will it be such an improvement? this module is part of complicated program and it would take days to convert it to compiled language

Comment: see serge-sans-paille answer, I didn't know about pythran, but what he shows is basically a speedup of like 3. Of course this is problem dependent, but I'd guess that for larger problems this gets even more important. As I said, you could think of implementing it in a compiled language and call it from Python, while this is somewhat involved, the rest of the application might remain unchanged. This Pythran suggestion basically automates that for you.

Comment: Just using numpy the best I could get was a factor of 1.8 speedup. You can take the `linalg.norm` line out of your `ITERATIONS` loop for a decent speedup, but I guess that's in there for stability? You can speed that line up using `x0 /= math.sqrt(np.dot(x0, x0))` instead of `x0 = x0/np.linalg.norm(x0)`. A little more speed from using `out=` arguments and doing some operations in place. Surprisingly (to me) `np.einsum` didn't help anywhere; `np.inner` and `np.dot` are pretty quick.

Answer (score 9):

You could consider using [Pythran](http://pythran.readthedocs.io). Compiling the following code (`norm.py`):

```
#pythran export powerA2(float [][], float[])
import numpy as np

def P(z, u0):
    x = np.inner(z, u0)
    tmp = x*u0
    return (z - tmp)

def norm(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(x)**2))

def powerA2(A, u0):
    ITERATIONS = 100
    x0 = np.random.random(len(A))
    for i in range(ITERATIONS):
        x0 = P(np.dot(A, x0), u0)
        x0 = x0 / norm(x0)
    return (np.inner(np.dot(A, x0), x0))
```

with:

```
pythran norm.py
```

yields the following speedup:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; A = np.random.rand(100, 100); B = np.random.random(100); import norm' 'norm.powerA2(A, B)'
100 loops, best of 3: 3.1 msec per loop
$ pythran norm.py -O3 -march=native
$ python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; A = np.random.rand(100, 100); B = np.random.random(100); import norm' 'norm.powerA2(A, B)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 937 usec per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! Will it still run for (much) larger matrices?

Comment: It's storing data as plain flat arrays, and avoids temporaries as much as possible, so as long as the matrix fits in memory, I'd say yes.

Answer (score 2):

Just to check: you want to do 10^4 operations of something 10^10... so even if your operation is O(1), that's still 10^14 operations, which is a pretty hard problem (and as haraldkl pointed out in his comment, this is also eating a ton of memory)  Just to check: are you going to call powerA2 10,000 times, or is 10,000 your desired value for ITERATIONS.  If the former, you could use threads (or better yet, separate processes) to get some parallization but I don't know if that's going to be enough; if the latter, unless there's a trick I'm missing, your inputs don't seem as paralizable since the input for each loop iteration depend on the outputs of the previous.  There may be a way to do this on GPU (I would like to think there'd be an efficient way to at least do the normalization bit such that it could do large numbers of stuff quickly by using vectorization)

Edit in response to comment: cpython (which is the most common python implementation) has a Global Interpeter Lock (GIL); some other python implementations (jython, ironpython) do not; per https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock, .

> Note that potentially blocking or long-running operations, such as
>   I/O, image processing, and NumPy number crunching, happen outside the
>   GIL. Therefore it is only in multithreaded programs that spend a lot
>   of time inside the GIL, interpreting CPython bytecode, that the GIL
>   becomes a bottleneck.

As far as I know, it should be possible to use threads with numpy and not be horribly bottlenecked but your problem still looks hard to convert to threads unless there's some bit of math I'm missing.

Comment: I read that python has interpreter lock, so, does multiple threads can work out in python?

Answer (score 2):

I get a 10% improvement over the uncompilled serge-sans-paille version by redefining functions this way:

```
def P0(z, u0):
    x = np.inner(z, u0)
    x *= u0
    return (z - x)

def norm0(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(x*x))

def powerA20(A, u0):
    ITERATIONS = 100
    x0 = np.random.random(len(A))
    for i in range(ITERATIONS):
        x0 = P0(np.dot(A, x0), u0)
        x0 /= norm0(x0)
    return (np.inner(np.dot(A, x0), x0))
```

Doing things like `*= u0` instead of `x = x*u0` avoids unnecesary copies of the variables in RAM, speeding the program up a little bit.
Also, you don't need `abs` in that case. And finally, `x*x` is slightly faster than `x**2`.